# 301 redirect error with wordpress and apache

Tags: wordpress

I've recently migrated a database from windows using bitnami (apache and wordpress) to a linux server (apache and wordpress). I'm able to access the website wp-admin, but every time I try to access the main site it repeatedly returns 301 errors.

I've tried disabling the .htaccess file (deleting, commenting everything out), but it still gets directed. I've disabled all plugins. I've looked into the themes I'm using but they don't have redirect url's like I've seen in other posts.

I'm wondering if the issue might be in how bitnami structures itself. the main documents are stored in website/wordpress/htdocs, whereas linux wordpress seems to store it directly in wordpress.

I've set sites-enabled home directory to

```
 sitelocation/wordpress/htdocs
```

I've also set the wordpress address and site address to

```
http://website.com:80
```

What do I need to do to prevent the redirects, or set it up to work correctly?

Comment: why you want :80 after website.com?

Comment: I guess I don't need it unless I'm doing a different port than 80, right? Would that be enough to cause an error or does it just look weird?

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't change your **Site URL** then.

Please change the **Site URL** and **Home URL** from database in **wp_option** table.

You need to mention new url in both section..

[image: Please check attached screenshot]

Comment: I tried changing that, but it didn't help anything. I had to do that to get wp-admin working in the first place, but I'm still getting 301 redirect errors

Comment: Please check your Files and folder permissions once..
Because in some server, issue occurs, that server will automatically change files and folder permissions.
Please make file to 644 and folders to 755

Answer (score 0):

I had a trailing / on my siteurl which led to it not working. After removing that it worked.